# How to sniff a serial connection of a Java app

Tags: java, python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to discover the connection parameters to a Java application. According to the status bar on the Java app, the connection values are: com1, 4800-baudrate, 8-eightbits, 1-stopbits, e-parity). However, when using pySerial to make a connection to the device (embedded Linux device -Ubuntu), I'm getting an access denied response. I feel that com1 is being used with a port number or something. At any rate, here is what I'm using:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
       port='COM1',
       baudrate=4800,
       parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
       bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)


ser.open()
ser.isOpen()


print ser.baudrate()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\file.py", line 12, in <module>
ser.open()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 56, in open
raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
SerialException: could not open port COM1: [Error 5] Access is denied.
```

I appreciate any help and/or direction given.

Comment: Two processes cannot access the same serial port at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I close the Java app, when I attempt with pySerial.

Comment: These questions probably have a solution for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032568/using-serial-on-python-win7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290913/pyserial-error-5-access-is-denied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063257/trying-to-open-a-serial-port-with-pyserial-on-winxp-access-denied

Comment: It is extremely uncommon to use parity.

Answer (score 0):

You cant open if already is open(try com port spliting with anyone software)
`serial splitter`
İf you got 2 serial port, make  sniffer with a cable...

Best regards